# Cannot install Java EE 7 SDK: null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, installation

I have stumbled upon a strange issue: after downloading the standard Java EE SDK bundle (without JRE), I cannot seem to install it. The installer itself launches properly, but will not progress past installation type selection dialog.

This would not be a problem at all, except that the installer is extremely uncooperative in trying to identify the issue, as can be clearly seen in this image:
[image: Detailed information is shown below: null]

> The names of the installation log and summary files are timestamp-
>   install.log and timestamp- install-summary.html. On Solaris, Linux,
>   and Mac OS X systems, these files are generated in the $TMP directory.
>   On Windows systems, these files are generated in the %TEMP% directory.

No such files are present in %TEMP%.

In case someone reviews only titles of related questions, here's a JRE presence validation:
[image: JAVA_HOME and <code>java</code> on PATH]